# Error al ejecutar un programa en C

Tags: c, dev-c++

soy principiante y estoy haciendo un programa que al momento de copilar en dev c++, no me indica ningún error,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(){
    int n,contadorM,contadorF;
    int edad,edadM,edadF,edadMAcumulado=0,edadFAcumulado=0;
    char genero;
    int prom, promedioedadM,promedioedadF;
    
    printf("Ingrese un numero de personas:");
    scanf("%i",&n);
    
    int i; for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        printf("Ingrese el genero de la persona (M)(F):");
        scanf("%i",&genero);
        
        if(genero=='M'){
            printf("Ingrese la edad:");
            scanf("%i",&edadM);
            edadMAcumulado=edadMAcumulado+edadM;
            contadorM++;
        }
        else if(genero=='F' ){
            printf("Ingrese la edad:");
            scanf("%i",&edadF);
            edadFAcumulado=edadFAcumulado+edadF;
            contadorF++;
        }
}

    promedioedadM=edadMAcumulado/contadorM;
    promedioedadF=edadFAcumulado/contadorF;
    
    printf("El promedio de la edad de los hombres fue de:%i",promedioedadM);
    
    printf("El promedio de la edad de las mujeres fue de:%i",promedioedadF);
            
return 0;}
```

pero al ejecutarlo, me ocurre esto, deja de trabajar después que indico el primer genero, no funcionando desde cliclo for, alguien que me pueda decir que estoy haciendo mal, please!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código va como texto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes algunas variables que no ocupas, yo habitualmente ocupo fflush para limpiar el buffer, para que no se repitan por ejemplo "ENTER'S" antes de ingresar el numero de personas, pero asi quedaria tu programa como lo tienes

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(){
    int n,contadorM=0,contadorF=0;
    int edadM,edadF,edadMAcumulado=0,edadFAcumulado=0;
    char genero;
    float promedioedadM,promedioedadF;
    
    printf("\nIngrese un numero de personas:");
    fflush( stdin );
    scanf("%i",&n);
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Ingrese el genero de la persona (M)(F): ");
        fflush( stdin );
        scanf("%c",&genero);
        if (genero== 'M'||genero== 'm')
        {
            printf("Ingrese la edad: ");
            fflush( stdin );
            scanf("%i",&edadM);
            edadMAcumulado+=edadM;
            contadorM++;
        }
        else if(genero== 'F'||genero== 'f')
        {
            printf("Ingrese la edad: ");
            fflush( stdin );
            scanf("%i",&edadF);
            edadFAcumulado+=edadF;
            contadorF++;
        }
    }
    promedioedadM=edadMAcumulado/contadorM;
    promedioedadF=edadFAcumulado/contadorF;
    
    printf("\nEl promedio de la edad de los hombres fue de:%f",promedioedadM);
    
    printf("\nEl promedio de la edad de las mujeres fue de:%f",promedioedadF);
            
return 0;
}
```

si quieres ver el contador y la edad acumulada añade las siguientes partes debajo de **contadorM++;**

```
            printf("\n %i",edadMAcumulado);
            printf("\n %i",contadorM);
```

Aplica lo mismo en el caso de **contadorF++;**

```
            printf("\n %i",edadFAcumulado);
            printf("\n %i",contadorF);
```